# Shiny App Not Running in Shinyapps.io (Error: Object UI Not Found)

Tags: r, user-interface, deployment, shiny

I have successfully run the following Shiny App locally.  Unfortunately, when I run it in shinyapps.io, I get the following error message from my log: Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found.  Even after extensive tracing, I could not find anything else that points to why ui could not be found, and again it can run locally.

Here is the complete log:

```
tidyverse_conflicts() ── ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter() ✖ dplyr::lag() masks stats::lag() 

Warning: replacing previous import ‘mgcv::multinom’ by ‘nnet::multinom’ when loading ‘cfbscrapR’ 

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’: dataTableOutput, renderDataTable 

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’: serverInfo Attaching package: ‘rsconnect’ 

64: shinyApp Warning: Error in force: object 'ui' not found –
```

Here is my code for ui.R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cfbscrapR)
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(rsconnect)
library(logger)

###Now create the ui function

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h1("College Football Analytics")),
  sidebarPanel(
    checkboxGroupInput("selections", label = h2(
      "Choose Weeks to Analyze"),
      choices = list("Week 1" = 1, "Week 2" = 2,
                     "Week 3" = 3, "Week 4" = 4,
                     "Week 5" = 5, "Week 6" = 6,
                     "Week 7" = 7, "Week 8" = 8,
                     "Week 9" = 9, "Week 10" = 10,
                     "Week 11" = 11, "Week 12" = 12,
                     "Week 13" = 13, "Week 14" = 14,
                     "Week 15" = 15),
      selected = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11",
                   "12", "13", "14", "15")),
    actionButton("submit", "Update")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h2("2019 Season"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
    theme = shinytheme("cerulean")
  )
)
```

And as for server.R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cfbscrapR)
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(rsconnect)
library(logger)

pbp_2019 <- read.csv("pbp_2019.csv")
drives_2019 <- read.csv("drives_2019.csv")


#Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cfb.table2 <- reactive({
    input$submit
    isolate({
      req(input$selections)
      new.pbp_2019 <- subset(pbp_2019, week %in% input$selections)})
  })
  plays <- reactive({cfb.table2() %>% filter(rush == 1 | pass == 1)})
  offense <- reactive({plays() %>% group_by(offense_play) %>% summarise(ypa = mean(yards_gained[pass==1]), ypr = mean(yards_gained[rush==1]), num.plays = n()) %>% filter(num.plays > 300)})
  offense <- reactive({plays() %>% group_by(offense_play) %>% summarise(epa.pass.off = mean(EPA[pass==1]), success.rate = mean(success), epa.rush.off = mean(EPA[rush==1]), num.plays = n()) %>% filter(num.plays > 300)})
  defense <- reactive({plays() %>% group_by(defense_play) %>% summarise(epa.pass.def = mean(EPA[pass==1]), epa.rush.def = mean(EPA[rush==1]), num.plays = n()) %>% filter(num.plays > 300)})
  update.epa <- reactive({left_join(offense(), defense(), by = c("offense_play" = "defense_play"))})
  drives.table2 <- reactive({
    input$submit
    isolate({
      req(input$selections)
      new.drives_2019 <- subset(drives_2019, week %in% input$selections)})
  })
  games <- cfb_game_info(2019) %>% rename("game_id" = id)
  drives.off <- reactive({drives.table2() %>% left_join(games, by = c("game_id")) %>%
      mutate(
        adj_start_yardline = ifelse(offense == away_team, 100-start_yardline, start_yardline), 
        success = ifelse(drive_result %in% c("TD", "FG"), 1, 0),
        drive.pts = ifelse(drive_result == "TD", 6, ifelse(drive_result == "FG", 3, 0))) %>%
      group_by(offense) %>% 
      summarise(
        fp = mean(adj_start_yardline[adj_start_yardline > 10 & adj_start_yardline <40]), 
        srate = mean(success),
        drives = n(),
        drives.pts = sum(drive.pts))
  })
  drive.update.epa <- reactive({left_join(update.epa(), drives.off(), by=c("offense_play"="offense")) %>%
      mutate(pts.per.drive = drives.pts / drives)})
  cfb.table3 <- reactive({data.frame(drive.update.epa() %>% 
                                       select(offense_play, success.rate, epa.pass.off, epa.rush.off, epa.pass.def, epa.rush.def, fp, drives, pts.per.drive) %>% gt() %>%
                                       tab_header(title = "2019 Season"))})
  output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(cfb.table3(),
              rownames = FALSE, 
              class = 'cell-border stripe',
              colnames = c('Team', 'Success Rate',
                           'Pass EPA', 'Run EPA',
                           'Pass EPA Def.',
                           'Run EPA Def.',
                           'Avg. Field Position',
                           'Drives',
                           'Points Per Drive'),
              list(pageLength = 25)) %>%
      formatPercentage(c('success.rate'),1) %>%
      formatRound(c('epa.pass.off'),3) %>%
      formatRound(c('epa.rush.off'),3) %>%
      formatRound(c('epa.pass.def'),3) %>%
      formatRound(c('epa.rush.def'),3) %>%
      formatRound(c('fp'),1) %>%
      formatRound(c('pts.per.drive'),3)
  })
}

#Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That's most likely because there's a related error somewhere *before* that error that is preventing `ui` from being properly defined. Were there any previous warnings or errors that might support this theory? (Perhaps `there is no package called ...`?)

Comment: tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
Warning: replacing previous import ‘mgcv::multinom’ by ‘nnet::multinom’ when loading ‘cfbscrapR’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’:
dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
serverInfo
Attaching package: ‘rsconnect’
64: shinyApp
Warning: Error in force: object 'ui' not found

Comment: Please just edit your question and put it there. Comments are horrible for that kind of stuff (code, data, newline-embedded stuff, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/two-file.html references a two-file shiny app. Before version 0.10.2, it was a requirement. From that page (as well as https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/app-formats.html):

> *For applications defined this way, the `server.R` file must return the `server` function, and the `ui.R` file must return the UI object (in this case, the UI object is created by `fluidPage()`). In other words, if the files contained other code (like utility functions) you must make sure that the last expression in the file is the server function or UI object.*

Specifically, *"contained other code"* includes ending `server.R` with `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`, which does *not* "return" the server object.

So there are three things wrong here:

- The `server.R` file should end with the `server` object, either its definition is the last thing in that file, or you must add `server` as the last line of code in that file.
- Since you're using the two-file system, you do not need to use `shinyApp(ui, server)`.
- However, since you did, the `ui` object is not defined or available in `server.R`. (In fact, I don't know if you can safely assume the order of files being `source`d, so one hack might be to `source("ui.R")` in `server.R`, but I don't think that's what you need.

Possible solutions:

1. Combine these two into a single file, perhaps the `app.R` setup that is references in the second link above. With that, keep the `shinyApp(ui, server)` call.
2. Keep the files as they are, and remove the call to `shinyApp`.

Comment: I kept the files the way they were, removed the 'shinyApp' call and included the two files I previously scraped, called into the two files.  It worked.  Thank you immensely!!!!!!!